# Automatic Uploading via FTP

Tags: upload, ftp

I am not sure if this is the right place to put this question

I want a good FTP Client which can upload the files to the server if any changes are made to a particular file in the directory its watching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

google 'windows ftp syncing' (I'm assuming windows) there's a pile of them.

hth